# Python not correctly finding value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this coding challenge:
Given an array of ints, return True if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.

```
def array_front9(nums):
    end = len(nums)
    if end > 4:
        end = 4
    for i in range(end):
        if nums[i] == 9:
            return True
        elif nums[i] != 9:
            return False
```

It is only passing about half the test cases, [as can be seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uFea.jpg)

I have only been coding for about a week now, and I cannot figure out why my code is not passing the test cases. Can someone please explain why it is failing those test cases and what I need to change to fix it?

Comment: Please post your code as well as full error in written form.

Comment: Hint: slice notation (`lst[:]`), and the `in` operator…

Comment: Your `return False` is too early. Your function is currently "is the first element == 9" because you return False if `a[0] != 9`. You need to move the `return False` to happen after _every_ element has been tested.

Comment: But I agree with @deceze, there are much better and simpler ways to do this

Comment: Thanks everyone, i understood the error and pardon me for the kind of mess i posted as it is my first time using these platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def is9(nums):
    return 9 in nums[:4]
```

Comment: Why the `if..else`?

Comment: What happens if you do `[:4]` on a list shorter than 4…?

Comment: Okay. Next reduce it even more to `return 9 in nums[:4]`…

Comment: I know there are shorter ways to do it but as a beginner I am not very comfortable with short methods, eventually i'll learn. Thanks again.